# Quotes Message | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed, quotes, helper

Hey i want to make the quotes to an embed be like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/564032243836780558/772176659175440455/unknown.png but the bot send it like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/564032243836780558/772176979406356520/unknown.png

Here is my code:

```js
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setDescription('<@&772162600275279883> `15`\n\n>>> **1 αμάξι.**/ \n\n>>> **25 repair kits.**')
            message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the description of an embed or an embed field you can use [markdown language](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/).

With that you can use the blockquotes as you want to do here.

```
.setDescription('> This is a blockquote');
```

You can also do bold, italic or code.

```
.setDescription('**Bold**, *Italic*, `code`');
```